# how can I get the background to cover the screen. in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

[image: I need the status bar and the bottom to be the same color]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height:"100%",
        width:"100%"
      },
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: You're probably using a Safe Area View outside of the container, simply move it inside of the container, inside of the background view

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <SafeAreaView>
     {... rest of the code}
     </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
```

if you are not using it in your main code it must be there in app.js or whatever the file you wrapped your navigation in.